# How call presentViewController from UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have 2 UIView and 2 UIviewController like below:

```
 //define my view class
 class myV1 : UIView {

     v1Ctrl : V1ViewController!
      //init view
      init() {

super.init(frame: UIScreen.MainScreen().bouns)
//create button in order to transfer to other viewcontroller
var btn : UIButton = UIButton()
btn.addTarget(self, action : "btnFunc:", forControlEvents : UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
// and add more like settitle and setTitleColor and etc, Finally add to view
  view.addSubView(btn)
     }

init(coder aDecoder :NsCoder) {
 super.init(coder : ADecoder)
     }
 }

  func btnFunc(sender : UIButton!) {

     v1Ctrl = V1ViewController()
     v1Ctrl.presentViewController(SecondViewController(), animated : true, completion : nil)     

 }
```

and other view is same as myV1

My V1ViewController is like below:

```
class V1ViewController : UIViewController {

var V1 : Myv1!

override func viewDidLoad() {

V1 = Myv1()
 self.view.addSubView(V1) 
     }
}
```

My Application working without Storyboard and Segue to transition between viewControllers.

That problem is that after I run application and touch on btn get an Error:
whose view is not in window hierarchy!

any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are instantiating a new UIViewController here

```
func myV1(sender : UIButton!) {

     v1Ctrl = V1ViewController()
     v1Ctrl.presentViewController(SecondViewController(), animated : true, completion : nil)     

 }
```

And the `v1Ctrl`, which now should present a new UIViewController, is not added to the Window hierarchy before.

Generally, you should think about your architecture because a UIView should not be responsible for creating a new UIViewController and present it.

The quickest fix for your problem should be to assign the `v1Ctrl`var in `viewDidLoad` of class `V1ViewController` like and remove the line `v1Ctrl = V1ViewController()`

```
class V1ViewController : UIViewController {

    var V1 : Myv1!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       V1 = Myv1()
       V1.v1Ctrl = self
       self.view.addSubView(V1) 

   }
}
```

.

```
func myV1(sender : UIButton!) {

     v1Ctrl.presentViewController(SecondViewController(), animated : true, completion : nil)     

 }
```